# How to align elements (section against header) within HTML using CSS with no space showing

Tags: html, css, layout

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: #BDF7EC;
 background-image: url('../images/flywheel.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
 text-align: center;
}

h1{
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 150%;
}

h2{
 font: bold 150% Arial, Verdana;
}

p{
 font: 100% Arial, Verdana;
}

nav a{
 color:#0B0B0B;
 background: #f0f4f4;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 13%;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 1.5% 0;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin: 1% 5% 1% 5%;
}
.active {
 background:#ffffff;
 color: #111109;
}
a:hover{  
    background: #B3B3B3;
    color: #0006CC;
}

a:focus{ 
    background: #ff8080;
    color: #ffffff;
}

a:active{ 
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}

.left{
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 500px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-right: 3%;
 display: inline-block;
 background: #3CA230;
 text-align: center;
}

img{
 display: block; 
 width: 60%;
 border: 2px solid #000000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 margin-top: 2%;
}

.right{
 width: 80%;
 height: 500px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*The table should be styled using at least four properties*/  
.right table{
 width: 70%;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
 line-height: 150%;
 text-align: center;
}

/*The table elements < td > should be styled using at least four properties*/
.right table td{
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
 line-height: 150%;
 text-align: center;
}

/*Set the opacity of the table rows to a value between .6 and .8 (make sure it is still visible)*/
.right table tr{
 background-color: #66ff66;
 padding: 2%;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/*Change the opacity of a row when it is hovered over*/
.right table tr:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}

/*The table headings should have a border, background color, and at least one other property.*/
/* (Are ONLY the corners of the table styled?)*/
.right table th{
 border: solid #00ff00;
 border-width: thin thin thick thin;
 padding: 2%;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #008000;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#1aff1a, #004d00);
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

/*Style the table so that the text in the first column is left-aligned and the text in the other two columns is centered*/
.right table tr td:first-child{
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 2%;
}
.right table tr th:first-child{
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ultimate Frisbee - History</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
  <nav>
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
   <a href="history.html" class = "active">History</a>
   <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
  </nav>
 </header>
  <main>
   <aside class = "left">
   <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/> </a>

   <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>


   <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
  </aside>
  <section class = "right">

 <h2>Background</h2>
 <p>Ultimate Frisbee/Ultimate has been around in some fashion since the 1960s.  Joel Silver is credited with introducing the game to his high school in 1968 after learning about the game at summer camp.  The game spread to more college campuses soon afterward.</p>
 <p>The Ultimate Players Association was founded in 1979 and began organizing touraments across the country.  In 2010, UPA because the <a href = "htpp://http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html">USA Ultimate</a>.</p>
 <p>Other than professional tournaments, games of Ultimate are typically played without referess.  Instead, players rely on "The Spirit of the Game" to encourage sportsmanship and self-officiating.</p>
 <h2>Sources</h2>

 <ul>
  <li><a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_(sport)">Ultimate (sport)</a></li>
  <li><a href = "http://www.wfdf.org/">World Flying Disc Federation</a></li>
 </ul>
 </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot change the HTML, only CSS. I would like the header to have no gap/space below it (above the .left aside and .right section). Currently there is a very obvious gap between the two, I am hoping to have them flush against each other. 
Pre-warning - I am amateur at this, first question here so basic code would be appreciated, thanks very much

I have checked my margins (no relevant margins seem to be an issue) and made all elements "border-box", I'm mainly using percentages for height and width. The HTML & CSS are both rather lengthy so haven't pasted full code, just relevant CSS. HTML has header, aside section with class .left and another section with class .right.
Let me know if I have omitted something you need, thanks

```
header{
width: 100%;
height: 20%;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #BDF7EC;
background-image: url('../images/flywheel.jpg');
background-size: cover;
padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.left{
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 500px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-right: 3%;
display: inline-block;
background: #3CA230;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.right{
width: 80%;
height: 500px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

Comment: Where is the HTML code?

Comment: Hi Pouya, sorry I didn't put it in as it is quite long but basically consists of <header> </header> <aside class = "left"> </aside> <section class = "right"> </section>

Comment: It would be hard to fathom the issue. I suggest you create a Fiddle..

Comment: Thanks Pouya, I have added snippet of all code, not sure what a fiddle is yet, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that your **h2** inside the section with the class **.right** is automatically set to **block** which eats up all the available **width** and **height**.

To **fix** **the issue** you can simply set the display of your **h2** to **display:inline-block**.